# How do I set up libgdx in netbeans?

Tags: android, libgdx

I've looked at other forums for this and they didn't help. And google/youtube doesn't really have much to say since most tutorials use Eclipse. But anyway, How do I exactly set up libGDX for Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the development environment by installing the JDK 7+. (Version 6 won't work), the Android SDK, [NBAndroid](http://www.nbandroid.org/), and [Gradle Support for NetBeans](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project).

For detailed step by step instructions, follow the [official wiki guide](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29). There's also an official [video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XlNYPFc9K8) in case you're a visual learner :)

Once, you're done, you can follow [these steps](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-NetBeans) to import and run your generated projects in NetBeans